# Get values form a txt, increase them save them in the same txt

Tags: python, string, variables, int

I'm trying to get some values from a txt, increase them (until here everything good) and then write the new variables on the file but I can't write the variables on the file although I've changed the variable in a string..
the code is

```
with open("setup.txt", "r") as f:
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
     str = line.split(",")
     if i == 0:
        minL = int(str[0])
        maxL = int(str[1])

        minL += 2
        maxL += 2
      elif i == 1:
        minF = int(str[0])
        maxF = int(str[1])
        minF += 1
        maxF += 1
minL = str(minL)
with open("setup.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(minL)
    f.close()
```

the txt is just:

```
15, 25
2, 9
```

EDIT*********
Sorry I just made a mistake when i copied the code, I've already put "w" for the writing mode but this doesn't work

the error is

```
line 15, in <module>
minL = str(minL)
NameError: name 'minL' is not defined
```

but I defined minL

Comment: Presumably it's complaining that you're trying to write to a file you just explicitly opened in `r`ead mode?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Also, when using `with open`, you don't need to `close`

Comment: The error message says that minL is not definded, so it seems that the for loop is never run. Maybe the file setup.txt is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `17` your expected output?

I copied and modified your code:

```
with open("setup.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        stri = line.split(",")
        if i == 0:
            minL = int(stri[0])
            maxL = int(stri[1])

            minL += 2
            maxL += 2
        elif i == 1:
            minF = int(stri[0])
            maxF = int(stri[1])
            minF += 1
            maxF += 1
minL = str(minL)
with open("setup.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(minL)
    f.close()
```

I got error with indentation (which I fixed) and changed `str = line.split(",")` to `stri = line.split(",")`

Comment: Thankyou, yes, the output shoud be 17! really appreciate!